# Curve traced by the centre of the circle containing radius of curvature

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

My teacher taught us the formula for calculating the radius of curvature of any curve but can we derive an equation for the curve made by the centre of circles contains the radius of curvature.

My attempt:
We can write the equation of tangent at any point and then we know the distance of center from that point using the radius. But this only gives one relation between the coordinates. How do we find the other equation?

Comment: If your curve is in the xy plane, then you only need to calculate the radius of curvature at a given point, and then go along the perpendicular to the tangent line a distance equal to the radius. [You of course need to know which way to travel since there are two directions to choose from, but that can be done via the second derivative of your curve.

Comment: The locus of centre of curvature (of plane curve) is known as an **evolute**.  Unwinding a curve gives an **involute**.  The involute of an evolute usually gives back the parent curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the locus of the center of curvature of a plane curve is called its evolute.  The equation of an evolute and its derivation are given in articles on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute) and [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Evolute.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha(s)$ be a unit-speed curve in the plane $\Bbb R^2$, parametrized by it's arc-length $s$.  Then the *unit tangent vector* to $\alpha(s)$ is given by

$T(s) = \dot \alpha(s), \; \; (1)$

and of course we have

$T(s) \cdot T(s) = 1, \; \; (2)$

from which

$\dot T(s) \cdot T(s) = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{ds}(T(s) \cdot T(s))$
$ = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{ds}(1) = 0, \; \, (3)$

which shows that $\dot T(s)$ is normal to $T(s)$, *always*.  If we assume

$\dot T(s) \ne 0, \; \; (4)$

we may write

$\kappa(s) = \vert \dot T(s) \vert \ne 0, \; \; (5)$

and set

$N(s) = \dfrac{\dot T(s)}{\kappa(s)} = \dfrac{\dot T(s)}{\vert \dot T(s) \vert}. \; \; (6)$

It is clear that

$N(s) \cdot N(s) = \dfrac{\dot T(s) \cdot \dot T(s)}{\vert \dot T(s) \vert^2} = \dfrac{\vert \dot T(s) \vert^2}{\vert \dot T(s) \vert^2} = 1 \; \; (7)$

and

$N(s) \cdot T(s) = \dfrac{\dot T(s)}{\kappa(s)} \cdot T(s) = \dfrac{\dot T(s) \cdot T(s)}{\kappa(s)} = 0. \; \: (8)$

Now, (6) yields

$\dot T(s) = \kappa(s) N(s), \; \; (9)$

the *first Frenet-Serret equation*; we call $\kappa(s)$ the *curvature* and $N(s)$ the *unit normal vector* to $\alpha(s)$.  If we differentiate (8) with respect to $s$ we obtain

$\dot N(s) \cdot T(s) + N(s) \cdot \dot T(s) = 0, \; \; (10)$

or

$\dot N(s) \cdot T(s) = -N(s) \cdot \dot T(s)$
$= -N(s) \cdot \kappa(s) N(s) = -\kappa(s); \; \; (11)$

also, (7) implies

$\dot N(s) \cdot N(s) = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{ds}(N(s) \cdot N(s)) = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{ds}(1) = 0; \; \; (12)$

it follows from (11) and (12) that

$\dot N(s) = -\kappa(s) T(s), \; \; (13)$

the *second Frenet-Serret equation*.  We next define the *radius of curvature* $\rho(s)$ *via*

$\rho(s) = \dfrac{1}{\kappa(s)}. \; \; (14)$

If we consider the circle in $\Bbb R^2$ passing through the point $\alpha(s)$, and whose unit tangent and normal vectors at $\alpha(s)$ are equal to those of $\alpha(s)$, respectively, and the curvature of which is $\kappa(s)$, then the radius of such a circle is $\rho(s)$ and the center of the circle is the point

$c(s) = \alpha(s) + \rho(s) N(s). \; \; (15)$

Now $c(s)$ in general varies with $s$, in accord with

$\dot c(s) = \dot \alpha(s) + \dot \rho(s) N(s)+ \rho(s) \dot N(s)$
$= T(s) + \dot \rho(s) N(s) + \rho(s) \dot N(s)$
$= T(s) + \dot \rho(s) N(s) - \rho(s) \kappa(s)T(s)$
$= T(s) + \dot \rho(s) N(s) - T(s) = \dot \rho(s) N(s). \; \; (16)$

From (14),

$\dot \rho(s) = -\dfrac{\dot \kappa(s)}{\kappa^2(s)}, \; \; (17)$

and thus

$\dot c(s) =  -\dfrac{\dot \kappa(s)}{\kappa^2(s)}N(s) = -\dfrac{\dot \kappa(s)N(s)}{\kappa^2(s)}; \; \; (18)$

the tangent vector to the curve $c(s)$ lies in the direction $-\dot \kappa(s)N(s)$; $\dot c(s)$ is not, however, a unit vector; indeed,

$\vert \dot c(s) \vert = \left \vert \dfrac{\dot \kappa(s)N(s)}{\kappa^2(s)}\right \vert$
$ = \dfrac{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert \vert N(s) \vert}{\kappa^2(s)} = \dfrac{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert}{\kappa^2(s)}, \; \; (19)$

which implies that $c(s)$ is a unit-speed curve precisely when

$\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert = \kappa^2(s), \; \; (20)$

i.e. when

$\dot \kappa(s) = \pm \kappa^2(s), \; \; (21)$

or

$\kappa^{-2}(s)\dot \kappa(s) = \pm 1; \; \; (22)$

now,

$\dfrac{d}{ds}(-\kappa^{-1}(s)) = \kappa^{-2}(s)\dot \kappa(s) = \pm 1, \; \; (23)$

whence

$-\kappa^{-1}(s) + \kappa^{-1}(s_0) = \pm \displaystyle \int_{s_0}^s du = \pm(s - s_0), \; \; (24)$

$-\kappa^{-1}(s) = -\kappa^{-1}(s_0) +  \pm (s - s_0), \; \; (25)$

$\kappa^{-1}(s) = \kappa^{-1}(s_0) \mp (s - s_0), \; \; (26)$

$\kappa(s) = \dfrac{1}{\kappa^{-1}(s_0) \mp (s - s_0)} = \dfrac{\kappa(s_0)}{1 \mp \kappa(s_0)(s - s_0)}$
$ = \kappa(s_0)(1 \mp \kappa(s_0)(s - s_0))^{-1}; \; \; (27)$

then

$\kappa^2(s) = \kappa^2(s_0)(1 \mp \kappa(s_0)(s - s_0))^{-2}; \; \; (28)$

also, (27) yields

$\dot \kappa(s) =  -\kappa(s_0)(1 \mp \kappa(s_0)(s - s_0))^{-2}(\mp \kappa(s_0))$
$= \pm \kappa^2(s_0)(1 \mp \kappa(s_0)(s - s_0))^{-2} = \pm \kappa^2(s), \; \; (29)$

in accord with (27).

Though $c(s)$ is not, in general a unit-speed curve, its unit tangent vector $T_c(s)$ may be expressed in terms of $\dot c(s)$ as

$T_c(s) = \dfrac{\dot c(s)}{\vert \dot c(s) \vert} = \dfrac{\kappa^2(s)}{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert} \dot c(s), \;\; (30)$

where $\vert \dot c(s) \vert$ is taken in accord with (19).  Furthermore, the arc-length $\sigma$ along $c(s)$ is given by

$\sigma_2 - \sigma_1 = \displaystyle \int_{s_1}^{s_2} \vert \dot c(t) \vert \; dt = \int_{s_1}^{s_2} \dfrac{\vert \dot \kappa(t) \vert}{\kappa^2(t)} \; dt, \;\; (31)$

which is equivalent to

$\dfrac{d\sigma}{ds} = \dfrac{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert}{\kappa^2(s)}, \;\; (32)$

which is in turn equivalent to

$\dfrac{ds}{d\sigma} = \dfrac{\kappa^2(s)}{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert}. \;\; (33)$

We are now in position to compute $dT_c(s)/d\sigma$, which in accord with the first Frenet-Serret equation applied to $c(s)$ yields

$\dfrac{dT_c(s)}{d\sigma} = \kappa_c(s)N_c(s), \; \; (34)$,

where $\kappa_c(s)$ and $N_c(s)$ are respectively the curvature and unit normal vector field of the curve $c(s)$; from (30) we have

$\dfrac{dT_c(s)}{ds} = \dfrac{d}{ds} \left (\dfrac{\kappa^2(s)}{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert} \dot c(s) \right ), \;\; (35)$

and thus,

$\dfrac{dT_c(s)}{d\sigma} = \dfrac{dT_c(s)}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{d\sigma} = \dfrac{d}{ds} \left (\dfrac{\kappa^2(s)}{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert} \dot c(s) \right )\dfrac{ds}{d\sigma}, \;\; (36)$

and now combining (33) and (34) with (36) we find that

$\kappa_c(s)N_c(s) = \dfrac{dT_c(s)}{d\sigma} = \dfrac{d}{ds} \left (\dfrac{\kappa^2(s)}{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert} \dot c(s) \right )\dfrac{ds}{d\sigma}$
$= \dfrac{d}{ds} \left (\dfrac{\kappa^2(s)}{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert} \dot c(s) \right )\dfrac{\kappa^2(s)}{\vert \dot \kappa(s) \vert}, \;\; (37)$

from which both $\kappa_c(s)$ and $N_c(s)$ may readily be had by taking the magnitude and direction of the expressions on the right-hand side.